# Can an existing Excel sheet be filled with data using an XSLT stylesheet?

Tags: c#, xslt

To answer this question I did a lot of googling, but did not find anything that clearly answers my question.

I just want to know if it is possible to edit an existing Excel Sheet via a stylesheet in C#.

The goal is that some existing Excel template can be used to add values from XML using a stylesheet

Comment: Please **[edit] the question** and define what you mean by `stylesheet` in this context. XSLT? Something else? Be clear please. Examples would also help very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Excel Object Model.

> Excel exposes this programmatic functionality through an object model. The object model is a collection of classes and methods that serve as counterparts to the logical components of Excel.

More information:

[How to automate Microsoft Excel from Microsoft Visual C# .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/automate-excel-from-visual-c)

[How to automate Excel by using Visual C# to fill or to obtain data in a range by using arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/automate-excel-using-visual-c-fill-data)